# Is there a more efficient way to get all the customer names and currency codes for the logged in user using google ads api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api

```
customer_service = client.get_service("CustomerService")
app_list = customer_service.list_accessible_customers().resource_names

def customer_query(client, customer_id):
    ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")
    query = """
        SELECT
            customer.descriptive_name,
            customer.currency_code
        FROM customer
        LIMIT 1"""

    request = client.get_type("SearchGoogleAdsRequest")
    request.customer_id = customer_id
    request.query = query
    response = ga_service.search(request=request)
    customer = list(response)[0].customer
    return customer

for entry in app_list:
    customer_id = entry.split('/')[1]
    entry = customer_query(client, customer_id)
    formatted_entry = {'customer_id': customer_id, 'name': entry.descriptive_name, 'currency': entry.currency_code}
    apps.append(formatted_entry)

return apps
```

This seems really convoluted and I'm having to pass around a lot more data than I'd like. Surely there should be a way to just request the details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this the exact code that you are using and it's working? It doesn't work as it is for me and I'm having trouble adapting it (I'm a Python beginner). I have https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/listing-accounts?hl=es-419 and other Google Ads API codes working, but not this one.

Comment: probably best to make a new stackoverflow post with any errors etc

Comment: Thanks @jake. I did that later (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76865344/google-ads-api-python-how-to-get-all-accounts-name-id-that-a-user-has-ac). No response yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is correct, you'll need to iterate over all accessible Google Ads accounts for the logged in user and then request details for them.

However, if any of those accounts is a manager account, then you'll want to use the `customer_client` resource instead as there might be many accounts under that manager account. Consider using a query such as

```sql
SELECT
  customer_client.id,
  customer_client.descriptive_name,
  customer_client.currency_code
FROM customer_client
```

Also note that in the manager account case, it's possible that you'll receive the same account multiple times if it's reachable from different accessible accounts. See the crudely drawn diagram below for an example:

```
                           ┌───────────────────────┐
                           │                       │
                           │ User's Google Account │
                           │                       │
                      ┌────┴───────────────────────┴────┐
                      │                                 │
                      │                                 │
            ┌─────────▼───────────────┐  ┌──────────────▼─────────┐
            │                         │  │                        │
            │ Ads Manager Account 1   │  │ Ads Manager Account 2  │
            │                         │  │                        │
            └──────────────────────┬──┘  └──────┬─────────────────┘
                                   │            │
                                   │            │
                                   │            │
                               ┌───▼────────────▼─┐  
                               │                  │
                               │  Ads Account A   │
                               │                  │
                               └──────────────────┘
```